# How can I grab a h1 tag with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-crawler, finance

I want to automatically grab the h1 tag from [yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NFLX?p=NFLX&.tsrc=fin-srch) for a given stock name (Netflix will serve as an example). This is what I got so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
 
driver = webdriver.Firefox() # Select the browser
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/') # Open the website

time.sleep(2)

try:
    driver.find_element_by_name("agree").click() #Check for cookie alert
except:
    print("No cookies today!")

searchbar = driver.find_element_by_id("yfin-usr-qry") #Find searchbar
searchbar.send_keys("NFLX") #Send the stock name
time.sleep(2)
searchbutton = driver.find_element_by_id("search-buttons") #Enter the search
searchbutton.click()

#This is where I need help

title = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("h1")

print(str(title))
```

Everything works fine until I try to get the header: **Netflix, Inc. (NFLX)** via *.find_element_by_tag_name("h1")*. The html source code looks like this:

```
<div class="D(ib) " data-reactid="6">
    <h1 class="D(ib) Fz(18px)" data-reactid="7">Netflix, Inc. (NFLX)</h1>
</div>
```

If the element I want to get has an id, then there is no problem accessing it through Selenium. The problem only occurs when I´m dealing with "weird" class names or missing id´s. Had this issue for several other websites as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location command was executed before the element was loaded. Thanks to rekeson21 I found two solutions to fix this problem:

```
time.sleep(6)
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1').text
print(title)
```

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

title = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h1/text()[contains(.,"NFLX")]/parent::*'))).text

print(title)
```

Output in both cases is:

```
Netflix, Inc. (NFLX)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're trying to do `str(title)` but it's just trying to print the element as a str but not printing the text of the element.

I would try to get it with an XPATH instead of a tag name.

Such as:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

title = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h1/text()[contains(.,"NFLX")]/parent::*'))).text

print(title)
```

Comment: Fair point with str(title) - thanks! I already tried xpaths (relative and absolute) but it didn´t work. Like your solution they throw the following exception:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //h1/text()[contains(.,"NFLX")]/parent::*`

Comment: Have you tried using WebDriverWait instead? I just edited my answer, check it out

Don't forget to add the following line ```from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC```

Comment: The location command was executed to early, so I added a `time.sleep(5)`. First solution works fine now, your second as well. I summarized the solution in an additional answer

Comment: Great to see it works. Using the WebDriverWait is more recommended than doing the time.sleep() plus, is more effective in case the element loads earlier than the specified seconds in the sleep.